# What does this error mean — Uncaught TypeError: Already read?

Tags: javascript, promise, typeerror

In Javascript, when is this error thrown?

[image]

**index.js**

```
/**
 * Created by tushar.mathur on 24/12/15.
 */
'use strict'

const _ = require('lodash')
const Rx = require('rx')
const createDataStore = require('./src/createDataStore')

const fetch = x => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(window.fetch(x)) 
const parseJSON = x => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(x.json()) // Line: 11 (Where the exception is thrown)
var create = _.partial(createDataStore, fetch, parseJSON)
module.exports = {
  create,
  // Alias for legacy purposes
  createDataStore: create,
  createFetchStore: create
}
```

Is it a native promise error? What does it imply? Google shows no result found.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I think it means that the body has already been read by using either .json() .text() etc... When you run x.json() it takes the response's body and reads it into JSON. If you try to run x.json() again it will give you that error. So you could only use one of [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) methods once. So I am assuming somewhere in your code it is reading the body of the same response again using one of the Body methods.

I think that is why they offer the `Body.bodyUsed` method. So you can see if it has been read already.

Comment: Solution if you really need to read 2x times: use response.clone() https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/196#issuecomment-171935172

Answer (score 18):

This error means you have resolved the promise (in this case, you use `Body.json()`) more than once.

You can check the response body methods from the ref I attached below and you need a flag to check if the promise has been resolved or not: in this case, you can use `Body.bodyUsed`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

HTH

Comment: I've just run into this error too. You don't need to resolve the promise twice, which should be impossible anyway without fiddling with internal properties of the promise. You only have to call `.then()` on it twice. It's documented that calling `.then()` twice is supported. I'll see if I can boil down a minimal example. My code displaying this is here: https://tonicdev.com/hippietrail/57611741f056621300ecd1e2

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue happens when using next js calling api from client side to next js server especially the usage of form data. For those who are looking for how to handle form data in next.js (v>=13), here's how I did:

1. Client

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file, file.name);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/{nextjs_server}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${token if needed}`,
      },
      body: formData,
      redirect: 'follow'
    });
```

2. Server (Next.js)

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
const formDataFlag = await req.formData() // this is the formData from the client
  if (formDataFlag) {
    const file = formDataFlag.get('file');
    
    const formDataToSend = new FormData();
    formDataToSend.append('file', file, file.name);

    const response = await fetch(`${actual api url}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token if needed}`,
      },
      body: formDataToSend,
      redirect: 'follow'
    })
    const textResponse = await response.text();
    return new Response(textResponse, { status: 200 });
  }
}
```

The key is to redefine formData (in my case it's formDataToSend). Happy coding!