# React Native fetch Network request failed,only use my API

Tags: react-native

Only user my API fetch Network request failed
use "https://api.douban.com/v2/movie/in_theaters" API is ok

react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.32.0

```
fetch('https://api.chooin.com/v1/product/index')
    .then((res) => alert(res))
    .then((data) => {
        // this.setState({
        //     loaded: true,
        //     products: this.state.products.cloneWithRows(data.subjects)
        // });
    })
    .done();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the first res into json

```
fetch('https://api.chooin.com/v1/product/index')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        return this.setState({
            loaded: true,
            products: this.state.products.cloneWithRows(data.subjects)
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I parse the first res,but also request failed.

Comment: So in ios8.3 you get the data but ios 10 not working ? The only way I was thinking was http and not https but your are already using https.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786358/what-does-this-error-mean-uncaught-typeerror-already-read

Comment: Yes, i use https, I fetch https://api.douban.com/v2/movie/in_theaters link http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/801b780ajw1f8f027h7sbj20ly10kjuy.jpg

Comment: @Devin, did you solve this? I am having the same problem