# How can I test a component created by asynchronous call in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm making a GET request to my API `http://localhost:3001/api/cards` from the componentDidMount function of a component, so that the api request is made only after the component is rendered for the first time (As suggested by react official guide).

This API sets the state of an array `data`. In render function, I call `data.map` function to render multiple components from this array. How should I test whether the desired number of components have been rendered?

My component:

```
//CardGrid.js

import React from 'react';
import { Card, Col, Row } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import { parseJSON } from './commonfunction';
import './CardGrid.css';

export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: {},
        };
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        try
        {
            const data = await parseJSON(await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/cards'));
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ data });
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            console.log('error is: ');
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ background: '#ECECEC', padding: '30px' }}>
                <Row gutter={16}>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((title) => {
                        return (<Col span="6" key={title}>
                            <Card title={title} bodyStyle={{
                                'fontSize': '6em',
                            }}>{this.state.data[title]}</Card>
                        </Col>);
                    })}
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Now I want to check if there are as many `Card` components being rendered as specified by my API.

I tried this by first mocking the `fetch` function to return 1 element. Then I use Full DOM Rendering of enzyme and `mount` the above component and expect it to contain 1 element.

Test case:

```
// It fails
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import CardGrid from './CardGrid';

it('renders 1 Card element', () => {
    fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve(mockResponse(200, null, '{"id":"1234"}')));
    const wrapper = mount(<CardGrid />);
    expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
    expect(wrapper.find(CardGrid).length).toEqual(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(Card).length).toEqual(1);
});
```

All the tests are passing except that it can't find Card element. Even the fetch mock function is called. It fails until I put a setTimeout function before I try to find Card component.

```
//It succeeds
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import CardGrid from './CardGrid';
it('renders 1 Card elements', async () => {
    fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve(mockResponse(200, null, '{"id":"1234"}')));
    const wrapper = mount(<CardGrid />);
    expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
    expect(wrapper.find(CardGrid).length).toEqual(1);
    await setTimeoutP();
    expect(wrapper.find(Card).length).toEqual(1);

});

function setTimeoutP () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('111111111');
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Is there any concept I'm failing to understand? How should I ideally test such asynchronously loading components? How can I better design them to be easily testable? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you really need `await parseJSON`? You didn't include that source but I'm guessing it's not async. The MDN docs say that "If the value is not a promise, it converts the value to resolved promise, and waits for it." so it seems like it should work, but maybe something with this approach and the testing framework?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the source of parseJSON. It basically calls `.json()` on the Response object returned by fetch API call. I need to await it as it returns a promise.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: In that case, I think the solution is to `await` BOTH promises (for `fetch` and for `parseJSON`).

Comment: On using `await (await result).json();`, I get `TypeError: Already read`. That is because body has already been read by using .json() and can't be read again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786358/what-does-this-error-mean-uncaught-typeerror-already-read

Comment: You have two Promises here, so both need to be resolved. You are mocking out the `fetch` to return a resolved promise so thats probably OK (along with the await from Andreas below), but seems like you _also_ need to mock out the `parseJSON` method e.g. `parseJSONPromise = Promise.resolve({"id": "1234"});` `parseJSON = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => parseJSONPromise);` and `await parseJSONPromise;` and `expect(parseJSON.).toBeCalled();`

Comment: see the updated answer from Andreas...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to [wait](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#async-await) for the resolved promise of your fetch result and for the promise from the `parseJSON`. Therefor we need to mock `parseJSON` and let it return a resolved promise as well. Please note that the path needs to be relative to the test file.

```
import {parseJSON} from './commonfunction'

jest.mock('./commonfunction', () => {parseJSON: jest.fn()}) //this will replace parseJSON in the module by a spy were we can later on return a resolved promise with


it('renders 1 Card elements', async () => {
    const result = Promise.resolve(mockResponse(200, null, '{"id":"1234"}')) 
    parsedResult = Promise.resolve({"id":"1234"})
    parseJSON.mockImplementation(()=>parsedResult)
    fetch = jest.fn(() => result)
    const wrapper = mount(<CardGrid />);
    await result;
    await parsedResult;

    expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
    expect(wrapper.find(CardGrid).length).toEqual(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(Card).length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work without setTimeoutP. I even update() the wrapper in the last line

Comment: I think your answer will work if you add a mocked out `parseJSON` too. From the OP: `await parseJSON(await fetch(...` <- note two promises being resolved.

Comment: argh, you are right, this will make the test really hard to follow, will update the answer