# Why I can not unit test method `getGoods(): Promise<Good[]>` (service fetching data via Http)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, typescript, asynchronous

I have service named GoodsDataService. It fetches some data via Http service. [Here is it](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/blob/feature/add-logic/src/app/services/goods-data.service.ts#L9).

Constructor is:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

Function `getGoods`. It is fetching data via Http service, get method:

```
  getGoods(): Promise<Good[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.goodsUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Good[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Notice `toPromise` method. I learned it from [this Angular official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html).

Now about unit testing of `getGoods` method. Here is unit tests for GoodsDataService: [here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/blob/feature/add-logic/src/app/services/goods-data.service.spec.ts). [This is how I test this method](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/blob/feature/add-logic/src/app/services/goods-data.service.spec.ts#L51):

```
service.getGoods()
  .then(goods => {
    expect(goods.length).toEqual(10);
    expect(goods).toEqual([new Good()]);
  });
```

`getGoods` makes http call, so [I have to mock it](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/blob/feature/add-logic/src/app/services/goods-data.service.spec.ts#L31). Here is the code:

```
const mockResponse = [
  {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
  {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
];

mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
    body: JSON.stringify({data: mockResponse})
  })));
});
```

As the result I have green tests. But they can't be green because of this: `expect(goods).toEqual([new Good()]);`. Result must be red. Anyway, even if I put debugger in `then` success function (where is two of my expects situated) IDE will be stopped on the breakpoint, I will get this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

So, despite of I mock real http request with some data I get `undefined` in success handler which I pass to `then` of promise returned by `getGoods` method.

## My thoughts and researches

Maybe the problem is in [these lines](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list/blob/feature/add-logic/src/app/services/goods-data.service.ts#L19):

```
...
.then(response => response.json().data as Good[])
...
```

If I put debugger there I see that `response.json().data` is `undefined` each time. By the way this code fires two times (not once). I think this can be explained by rxjs (http.get returns observable and subscription fires not only once. If I check `response.json()` value it is Promise. It is rejected. There is some error stacktrace in it.

[image]

Here is it:

```
TypeError: Already read
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:56782:13), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:56782:13
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1546:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:55337:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1545:32)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1296:43)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1972:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1579:31)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:55361:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts:1578:36)
```

How this code was created? I learned from [this off tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) and [this great article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html). May be the problem is somewhere here: looks like the article author using another way to fetch data (he using only subscription, without promises). May be thats why my tests does not work.

Probably, my problem relates to [What does this error mean — Uncaught TypeError: Already read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786358/what-does-this-error-mean-uncaught-typeerror-already-read). But how to handle it?

Note, that if I use service in another components - everything works like a charm! For example this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.goodsDataService.getGoods()
    .then((data) => {
      debugger;
    })
}
```

Shows correct data (array) in `data`.

The question: what I am doing wrong?

Any thoughts?

Comment: replace `body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)` with `body: JSON.stringify({data:mockResponse})`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated my question. I tried it firstly (like it was in article), but it does not work. Even if I change code like you said, i have same results. I updated question and src on github.

Comment: May be this relates to my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786358/what-does-this-error-mean-uncaught-typeerror-already-read

Comment: Meh... The problem appeared because I forgot to import `Response` class =(